# how to run a code after firestore .update() is finished in server in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, angular9

i'm trying to send a locally generated token to store it in both **localstorage** and **firestore** when user login then routing user to admin component then in app component **subscribe** to the user and compare between the stored token and the **localstorage** stored user and if they are different to each other application will **logout** user
but the real scenario is when token changed in the localstorage it takes some times to change in firestore so the subscription notice that the 2 tokens (old token in firestore before it changed and new token stored in localstorage) are different then logged out user immediately

Answer (score 0):

You can write token to local storage after data is first updated in Firestore:

```
db.collection("collection").doc("doc").update(data)
.then( () => {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");

    window.localStorage.setItem( key, token );

})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

`db`, `"collection"`, `"doc"`, `key`, `token` are only representational. You should replace with your data.

Hope it helps! Happy coding!